# Which webpage broadcasts a single chess game, usually Carlsen's, in infinite analysis?

Tags: analysis, engines, carlsen

I would often visit a site that had a live Carlsen game analyzed by a strong computer, and deeper than the "average" chess site, but I can't seem to find it. I think it had something to do either with the TCEC or the Stockfish team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably thinking of [analysis.sesse.net](http://analysis.sesse.net/).